# DB2 Before Update Trigger Behavior

Tags: grails, db2, grails-orm

Wondering if someone can help me understand how a DB2 before insert trigger behaves. I have a Grails app that inserts rows to a DB2 database. The table in question has a before insert trigger that updates the date and user for the update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER WTESTP.SCSMA11I NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON 
WTESTP.SCSMA01T REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW FOR EACH ROW MODE 
DB2SQL BEGIN ATOMIC SET NEWROW.LST_UPDT_TMSP = 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ; SET NEWROW.USER_ID = RTRIM ( USER ) ; END ;
```

In my Grails application I set all the values, including the user id:

```
flatAdjustmentInstance.setUserID("TS37813")
```

We use a generic application ID and password via JNDI to make the connection to the database. For auditing purposes I need to set the value of the user to whomever logged into the application. Is the only solution to remove the trigger entirely and just be really sure it is set?

Comment: You question is little unclear, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Specifically I am looking to override the value the trigger is using to set the user_id field. I would think that since it is a before update it would use the incoming value, however the value is not changed.

Comment: Yes in that case I think you have get rid of the trigger, since Trigger will use the User info from the connection which would be `applicationID` in your case. This will be a bit of generalization, but you can add a logic in the trigger to check if a user_id is already sent from the application, then do not set the application user id in Trigger. This is my theory only to make sure you are not throwing away the trigger. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB2 `USER` variable (also called "special register") contains the authorization ID of the current database connection. If an application wishes to pass another user ID to DB2, it can do so by calling the API function `sqleseti()` or the stored procedure `WLM_SET_CLIENT_INFO()` -- [more info here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005868.html#r0005868). The trigger can then reference another special register, `CURRENT CLIENT_USERID`.