# use a db2 trigger to identify the user initiating

Tags: triggers, db2, db2-luw, userid

When creating a DB2 trigger (db2 version 10.1 LUW), I am looking to capture the userid that initiating the trigger.

For example, if a user inserts data, the after insert trigger should write to a log on who inserted the data.  This not meant for production purposes - just is to identify who is updating / inserting test data.

Comment: The database can log what queries have been run and what users have run them.  Why not use that functionality?

Comment: "db2 version 10" suggest DB2 for z/OS, is that correct?

Comment: Are you referring to the db2diag log?  We are using DB2 LUW.  Prefer to get the data via trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 Before Update Trigger Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676050/db2-before-update-trigger-behavior)

Comment: There's no "version 10 LUW".

Comment: Yes, we are running version 10 - - Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.0.5",   (per db2level)

Comment: That's 10.1, not 10 -- as opposed to 10.5, for example. These "minor" numbers are significant, as there's always new/changed/removed functionality between them.

Comment: Reviewing the article above and running this query:

select current client_userid, length (current client_userid)  from sysibm.sysdummy1 

Returns a length of zero (0).

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the value of the [SESSION_USER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011134.html) special registry variable. As an alternative look at the [SYSTEM_USER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011137.html) registry. There are differences if you use features like `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` or use `TRUSTED CONTEXTS`.

Try this as a quick test:

```
select session_user from sysibm.sysdummy1;
select system_user from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is helpful.  When putting this together, what is the correct syntax to incorporate this into a trigger:

create trigger userid.logchange
   after insert
   on userid.css_defn
   referencing new as n
   for each row mode db2sql
   begin atomic
      declare sessuser = select session_user  from sysibm.sysdummy1;
      declare sysuser = select system_user  from sysibm.sysdummy1;
      Insert into userid.applog (Description) values ('** Insert record **  css: ' || coalesce(rtrim(char(n.css_id)), '') || ' Session user : '
      || sessuser || ' System user :  '|| sysuser )

Comment: you don't need any select, just access session_user  in the definition of sessuser